# How can I click on the contact list (web.whatsapp.com)?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, whatsapp

Im trying to code an api for web.whatsapp.com. The js-code is injected with a firefox addon. But when I want to click on the contact list (dispatchEvent, click), nothing happens...
Here's the click function:

```
function Click(element){
    for(var i in element.children){
        try{
            Click(element.children[i]);
        }catch(a){}
    }
    var evt = new MouseEvent('mousedown', {
                                bubbles: true,
                                cancelable: true,
                            });
    element.click();
    element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Why doesn't it work and how can I solve this?

Comment: i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
function triggerMouseEvent(node, eventType) {
    var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initEvent(eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent(event);
}

triggerMouseEvent(document.getElementsByClassName("chat-title")[0], "mousedown");
```

I used this to generate a click on the contact [0] from my contact list, so it will do a click on contact.